# How can I place mutliple anchors while looping trough a list with the coordinates in ArCore for Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, anchor, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm looping trough a list with coordinates in it and want to place multiple anchors. Now only the last one get rendered because it overrides it.

```
//loop trough the items in array
for(item in a){
  //remove the { and } from the string
  var b = item.replace("}", "")
  b = b.replace("{", "")

  //split the string on the , to get the values
  var c = b.split(",")

  var x = (c[1].split(":")[1])
  var y = (c[2].split(":")[1])

  val anchor =
    session?.earth?.createAnchor(
      /* Locational values */
      x.toDouble(),
      y.toDouble(),
      session?.earth?.cameraGeospatialPose?.altitude?.minus(1)!!,
      /* Rotational pose values */
      0f,
      0f,
      0f,
      1f
    )
```

}

I don't mind the first steps for formatting de data from api call and making an array.

The item in the loop is an array with the first element being a name and the other two the coordinates.

Only the last item in the array is being created.